# How do I limit a Ubuntu machine to a Python GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, ubuntu, tkinter, restriction

I wrote a python GUI in Tkinter for a time-clock system. The micro machine is wall mounted and the employees only have access to the touchscreen menu I programmed and a barcode swipe. I know how to get the script to start on startup, but how do I prevent them from exiting out or opening other menus? Basically the sole purpose of this console is to run the time-clock GUI.

If it cant be done in Ubuntu, is there another flavor of linux it can be done in?

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, you might want to try the sister site: http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Thanks, good advice, I will definitely submit a question there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also de KDE Kiosk project, which you can install on a ubuntu machinne:
"
The KDE Kiosk is a framework that has been built into KDE since version 3. It allows administrators to create a controlled environment for their users by customizing and locking almost any aspect of the desktop which includes the benign such as setting and fixing the background wallpaper, the functional such as disabling user log outs and access to the print system and the more security conscientious such as disabling access to a command shell."

http://techbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/Kiosk/Introduction

Comment: I am glad you could set it up. After I answered this, I reaserched a bit more and found the project to be little active these days. I think it can work fine in a KDE 3.5 (instead of a modern KDE 4.x) setup, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wm_overrideredirect](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.overrideredirect-method), then make the UI full screen. This will remove all window decorations so there's no way to close the window. If that's not enough, as a final step you can do a global grab. With that, you effectively control everything that they can do.

Be *very* careful about coding global grabs -- make sure you can ssh into that box to kill the process, otherwise you can effectively denial-of-service your box.

Answer (score 1):

Don't start a window manager. Only start your program, e.g. from xinitrc. Make the program full-screen